# Powerpoint- fast ways to "insert and link" an image

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint

I make a lot of slides with png images (graphs made with matplotlib) that are frequently updated. I love being able to insert and link these images, since the slides stay up-to-date when the images are updated.

However, the mechanics of insert and link are slow and awkward (you have to click on "Insert", then "Picture", then "picture from this device", then click the "Insert" dropdown on the dialog box and change to "Insert and Link".) You can speed it up slightly by using alt-NPD but then you still need to change the dropdown on the dialog box.

Does anyone know any tips to speed this up further? For example, I would love to be able to drag an image into powerpoint and have it link itself automatically.

Comment: I don't know of any way to speed this up, unfortunately, but it's a great idea, one that I *think* I'll be able to add to a free ImageInsert add-in I've written the next time I have it open to work on.

Comment: Can be done with VBA. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56980726/inserting-and-linking-a-picture-into-a-shape-fill-using-vba) can get you started.

Comment: Good call, @harrymc.  J. Kelly, you'll want to scroll down to John Korchok's reply in that thread. The rest of the replies are either not related or sorta bad ways of going about solving the problem.

Comment: Thanks for those suggestions! I am going to try to do this through my python workflow using the python-pptx library. @SteveRindsberg, the ImageInsert tool looks really useful, would love to know whenever its updated.